# how to combine groupby, rolling and apply in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd
dd = pd.DataFrame({'group' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'value' : [1,2,30,10,2,30,12,30,1,1]})

dd
Out[32]: 
   group  value
0      1      1
1      1      2
2      1     30
3      1     10
4      2      2
5      2     30
6      2     12
7      2     30
8      2      1
9      2      1
```

I would like to apply `pd.qcut()` in a rolling fashion for each group.

Using the already available `rolling()` functions in pandas works well, with the only caveat that one needs to extract the `.values` of the series to be able to create a new variable in the existing dataframe. For instance with `rank()`:

```
dd['myrank'] = dd.groupby('group').rolling(2).value.rank()
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

while

```
dd['myrank'] = dd.groupby('group').rolling(2).value.rank().values
```

works

```
dd
Out[40]: 
   group  value  myrank
0      1      1     NaN
1      1      2     2.0
2      1     30     2.0
3      1     10     1.0
4      2      2     NaN
5      2     30     2.0
6      2     12     1.0
7      2     30     2.0
8      2      1     1.0
9      2      1     1.5
```

**Unfortunately**, I am not able to find a good working solution for any function that is not an official method of rolling, like `qcut`. For instance, this does not work:

```
dd['myqrank'] = dd.groupby('group').rolling(2).value.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2, labels = False))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Trying to be smarter and call `qcut` on the rolling data does not work either

```
dd['myqrank2'] = dd.groupby('group').value.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x.rolling(2), 2))
AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Any idea how to use `apply` with a generic function after a `rolling` and a `groupby` here?

Thanks!

Comment: `dd.groupby('group').rolling(2).value.rank()` returns the multi index series, which is not possible to assign to a column, but `.values` works.

Comment: thank you. but this is something I know already and rank() is an official method of rolling. My question is about all the other functions (like qrank). how can i get this groupby rolling apply pipe working correctly?

Comment: `qcut` returns a series. What would your expected output be? For example the row at index 1 will be in two rolling windows. Which quantile/rank would you want to assign?

Comment: @not_speshal very good point. the very last row for each window (the last rank, which corresponds to the rolling rank of the current observation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you're trying to apply return `pd.Series`. Since you want to assign the `qcut` value of the last value in each rolling window, you could use

```
>>> dd.groupby('group').rolling(2).apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2, labels = False, duplicates="drop").iat[-1])

         value
group         
1     0    NaN
      1    1.0
      2    1.0
      3    0.0
2     4    NaN
      5    1.0
      6    0.0
      7    1.0
      8    0.0
      9    NaN
```

Comment: As an aside, you can apply `rank` directly without `values`: `dd.groupby('group').rolling(2).rank()`

Comment: very nice. but how would you create a variable with this in the new dataframe? using .values I presume?

Comment: No need to use .values. Use the column name. In this case "value": `dd["rank"] = dd.groupby('group', as_index=False).rolling(2).apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2, labels = False, duplicates="drop").iat[-1])["value"]`